# Running ros image to cv image conversion node

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying the example node given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) to convert ros images into opencv images. When I run the node I don't see anything on the screen. My `Opencv version is 2.4.8` and am using `Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04`. Below is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(roscv_conv)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(roscv_conv_node src/roscv_conv_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(roscv_conv_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(roscv_conv_node sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Do I need to add anything to my `CMakeLists.txt` or is it because I need to install any additional drivers or a different version of opencv? I run the node and the cursor keeps blinking on the screen and doesn't display anything else. What am I missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241176/running-ros-image-to-cv-image-conversion-node/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-05**:
Are you running another ROS node that is publishing images?

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-08-05**:
I don't think so. I have installed [libuvc](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera) camera driver and am trying to figure out how to get it published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have realized that the problem was the absence of any nodes publishing images (I know, it's silly). I have got this working with the topic `/camera/rgb/image_rect_color`, using zed camera and its [ros wrapper](http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper). Thank you ahendrix.

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1